# It can work at Unity but it doesn't work at Android mobile phone

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Unity : 2017.2.0f3
Android SDK : 2.3.2
Java : 1.8
GVR SDK : 1.70
This is my tool version.

I want to make gaze to click. but It can work at Unity but it doesn't work at Android mobile phone.

[image]
[image]

it's my gaze to click code..plze solve this problem

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
public class gaze : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool gazeat = false;
    public float MyTime = 0.0f;
    public Transform RadialProgress;
    RaycastHit hit;
    void Start()
    {
        MyTime = 0.0f;
        RadialProgress.GetComponent<Image>().fillAmount = MyTime / 2;
    }
    public void reset()
    {
        MyTime = 0.0f;
        RadialProgress.GetComponent<Image>().fillAmount = MyTime / 2;
    }
   void Update()
    {
        MyTime += Time.deltaTime;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RadialProgress.GetComponent<Image>().fillAmount= MyTime/2;
        if (MyTime >= 2.0f)
        {
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                ExecuteEvents.Execute(hit.transform.gameObject, new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current), ExecuteEvents.pointerDownHandler);
                reset();
                this.enabled = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```